# Changing the text selection cursor

Tags: css, cursor

As the title says, is there a way to change the text selection cursor? Changing the cursor in CSS (eg. `cursor: hand`) just changes the normal cursor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258647/changing-the-highlight-color-when-selecting-text-in-an-html-text-input

Comment: That just seems to be about selection color, not the cursor.

Comment: http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm

Comment: Ah... oops... missread text selection cursor as text selection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313732/prevent-highlighter-cursor-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean “cursor” in the old sense–the thing that appears in editable text to indicate the location where text is to be inserted or where text deletion or insertion is to take place. Its appearance is, in modern systems, typically a blinking (appearing and disappearing) thin vertical line. I’m afraid there isn’t a way to change it, even as planned or proposed. If there were, I would expect to find it in the [CSS3 Basic User Interface Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/), where the `cursor` property is defined.

The CSS specifications and drafts reflect a new meaning for “cursor,” namely something that used to the called “pointer.” For further confusion, one of the possible values for `cursor` is `pointer` (typically, appearing as a hand).