# How to change appearance of "text-selection" cursor on webpages or disable cursor changing while a text is selected in all major browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

I want to prevent the mouse cursor from changing when I move it over some text. Is this possible?

If not, I would like to change the appearance of `text-selection` cursor - is it possible with css / javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

```
* {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

*:active,
*:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The idea of the site is that users have done some research and attempted something before asking questions. This is merely a hint and as relevant as it gets...

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work properly in Chrome - the cursor changes to cursor:text when you want to select some text.

Comment: Of course I tried, maybe bad explanation. In Chrome, when you start to select text, or just click and drag with mouse, cursor automaticcaly changes to "text-selection" cursor. How to prevent it?

Comment: You could leave off the `*` in your latest examples.

Comment: I need to keep user selection, I only don't want to cursor change - is this possible without disabling user selection?

Comment: It appears you cant, even setting an image for the cursor doesnt work   cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), pointer !important;

Answer (score 5):

Nobody feels like explicitly setting the cursor for each element, even if that only entails adding a class. That's a lot of hand work.

It would be wiser to:

```
* {
cursor: inherit;
}

body {
cursor: default;
}
```

This will disable the text selection cursor for any element, but won't interfere with any other CSS or scripts that change the cursor-property for certain elements.

Comment: Coupled with `user-select: none`, it's best for desktop-app-like behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are lookings for is the css property `"cursor:default;"` - but this really depends on what exactly you are looking for. Example with a label:

```
label{
    cursor:default;
}
```

Depending on the cursor you want, you can change the value from `"default"` to something else.

Here's a list of some of the values (Not all - but the most common are there):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor

Remember you get different results depending on browser/OS.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Yes, i CAN change a type of the cursor if I move it over some element, for example <p> element. BUT, if I start to selecting text, my cursor changes anyway - in Chrome.

Comment: @JiříZmrhal Sorry I don't think it is possible (misunderstood your question at first), I've searched around the internet(like you probably already have) and found nothing too. I also remembering trying to do this myself with dissappointment. This post draws the same conclusion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583785/changing-the-text-selection-cursor - However if  youd find an answer, please post it :)

Comment: Yes, maybe it isn't possible. But I think if disabling of cursor changing while selecting text works in IE, it must work in Chrome too - with text selection enabled, of course :).

Comment: Upvoting because I was looking for a way to make the "text" cursor disappear (I had text on top of a clickable td element, and it was getting in the way). This worked for me. Thanks, Peter.