# How to change qooxdoo editable fields selection color?

Tags: qooxdoo, theming

Is there a simple way to change the selection color in the various editable qooxdoo fields (all children of `qx.ui.form.AbstractField`). I would like to get rid of this light-blue selection that seems to be imposed by the browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be currently handled by qooxdoo themeing, but there is a solution by adding rules to the global qooxdoo stylesheet.

The key information you need is the `::selection` pseudo element. Please see documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/::selection and an answer for this on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681913/6255232 .

Using this information css rules can be added via `qx.ui.style.Stylesheet.getInstance().addRule` either globally for every selectable element or specifically for e.g. input und textarea.

The basic example for changeing the selection background color to red for all input elments would be:

```
qx.ui.style.Stylesheet.getInstance().addRule(
  "input::selection", 
  "background-color:#ff0000"
);
```

As the `addRule` method checks if the given rule is applicable to the current browser, you'll get an exception when trying to add a rule with the prefix like `-moz-` to a non gecko based browser. So you either have to handle this using browser engine switches or by trying with all prefixes and ignoring the exceptions.

```
var rules = [
  "input::selection,textarea::selection",
  "input::-moz-selection,textarea::-moz-selection",
  "input::-ms-selection,textarea::-ms-selection",
  "input::-webkit-selection,textarea::-webkit-selection"
];

for(var i=0;i<rules.length;i++) {
  try {
    qx.ui.style.Stylesheet.getInstance().addRule(
      rules[i], 
      "background-color:#ff0000");
  }
  catch(ex) {};
}
```

This should change the background-color of the selection for all input and textarea elements to red.

You may, of course, also change the text color by adding a `color`property to the rule.

And you could create a rule `*::selection` which will apply your changes to all elements.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the applied qooxdoo theme colors by name in this code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

One addition to my previous answer:

You could use a theme color by resolving the color name via

```
var cssColor = qx.theme.manager.Color.getInstance().resolve('my-theme-color-name');
```

and use that to compose the `background-color` or `color` property in the rules.

Note that if you use dynamic theme changes you have to re-apply the rules to reflect the different theme colors.